# How do you make the MGM filmstrip ribbon in Blender?

Tags: modeling

[image]

This is what I'm trying to talk about. Are there any possible ways to recreate the ribbon, complete with the holes, surrounding Leo the Lion in the MGM logo?

Comment: And you did try what? Or do you want us to make all the work for you?

Comment: Hi :). There sure are. But please show what you tried so far and where exactly you're stuck :). As Chris said, this site isn't meant for full tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

create a curve for your ribbon

[image]

create a plane, subdivide it a few times

[image]

create a cube as the hole like this:

[image]

add empty in 0/0/0 and a mirror modifier for cube

[image]

[image]

add boolean modifier for plane, make cube invisible:

[image]

[image]

add array modifier to plane, fit curve, choose curve

[image]

add curve modifier with your curve to your plane

[image]

add material

[image]

i hope you know how to add a picture...if not, please ask another question (you can ask as many questions as you like)

[image]